# Are basic mathematical functions optimized?

Tags: c++, c

Does a function such as

```
int GetSize(int type){
   switch(type){
       case 0:
          return 15 * 16 + 17 / 2;
       case 1:
          return 25 * 6 + 7 / 42;
   }
}
```

get optimized? I have a function such as this that will be called 100s of times per second but the return values for each case are always the same. I could put in a comment what each returned value represents if returning a hard coded value is that much faster, or I could leave it as such if the compiler pre calculates each result.

Comment: These days, I'd hope so. Check the generated assembly if you're in any doubt.

Comment: The compiler should evaluate those expressions and write a single value in the code to return.

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Disassemble if in doubt.

Comment: @Bathsheba My compiler produces one final image (vxWorks). How in heavens would I find that piece of code?

Comment: Aside: it might be a bad sign that the value of the expression is truncated when you are returning a size. In the second case `7 / 42` is `0`. Even if you parenthesize the first one as `(15 * 16 + 17) / 2` the odd numerator leads to a value that is rounded down.

Comment: Compilers do not produce images. They produce object files which are then linked and some other tool is embedding the linked binaries into specific images if needed. So if you want to know more about it you need to dive a bit deeper into your build process.

Comment: @bary_winkle_33 Your compiler will produce an object file from the file containing that source code. Most of the optmization will have been performed by that point. You can disassemble the object file to see the code generated. Or you could just put your code into this [site](https://godbolt.org/). All major compilers supported.

Comment: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does a function such as [...] get optimized?

[Yes, **heavily**](https://godbolt.org/z/haKvnK):

[image]

Comment: Output is from gcc 10 x64.

Comment: The warning in the link is interesting too.

Comment: Just beautiful, it inverts 0/1 (type variable), put result into Carry Flag, convert CF into 111...1 or 000...0 by sbb and then does an "AND" to the difference between 248 and 150

Answer (score 0):

This question is a prime example of why C and C++ are wholly different languages. The answer to your question depends on which language you are using.

For an answer to C++ see [Blindy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62959336/430766) which results in branch-free code. The C++ optimiser takes advantage of the fact that you fail to return for any other input value.

```
GetSize(int):
        cmp     edi, 1
        sbb     eax, eax
        and     eax, 98
        add     eax, 150
        ret
```

However, if compiled as C code, the [result](https://godbolt.org/z/nrjMox) is quite different as you suddenly have a jump in there.

```
GetSize:
        mov     eax, 248
        test    edi, edi
        je      .L1
        mov     eax, 150
.L1:
        ret
```

Comment: Removing the source of UB, you'll have the same result in C https://godbolt.org/z/b5EPMT

Comment: This difference may be caused by the compiler behaving differently for C versus C++, but it is not caused by differences in the language specifications. The same assembly/machine code would be acceptable for either language.